# Help to implement script that toggle single and double quotes

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

I have following

```
function! s:get_visual_selection()
    let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
    let [line_end, column_end] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
    let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)
    if len(lines) == 0
        return ''
    endif
    let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: column_end - 2]
    let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]
    return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction

" dependencies - tpope's surround.vim plugin
function! s:singleDoubleQuotesToggler() "{{{
  " select between "" using
  norm va"
  let doubleq_sel = s:get_visual_selection()
  " echo string(doubleq_sel)
  let doubleq_sel_length = strlen(doubleq_sel)
  echo string(doubleq_sel_length)
  exec "norm! \<Esc>"
  if doubleq_sel_length == 0
    " echo string("single")
    norm cs'"
  else
    " echo string('double')
    norm cs"'
  endif
endfunction "}}}

nnoremap <silent> GS :call <SID>singleDoubleQuotesToggler()<CR>
```

problem is that GS work through once and I dont know why

[video](https://asciinema.org/a/DeMsED2ul6EK5loaoKFyzssG3)

Comment: Have also a look here https://gist.github.com/romgrk/dc871a06975b787d70bc40e2cd7feeae and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129699/double-quotes-in-single-quotes-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

For your approach to work, you could define an `omap` that finds the smallest enclosing pair, and tests the character under the cursor to trigger the mapping from Surround you wish. I remember a plugin that has defined the operator pending mode you'll need. Its approach was quite smart by testing all possible `vi{whatever}` to find the one with the smallest result. From there, you'll just need to test the character under `'<`. Alas I can't remember the name of this plugin.

It seems I've implemented an equivalent in lh-brackets ([`s:outer_blocks()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/autoload/lh/brackets.vim#L592)), it doesn't returns the first characters, but the last one. From there, you'll just need to test the character under the closest position, and you'll know which surround mapping you want to execute.

That's the `if p[0] =~ '["'']'` part that'll be of interest to you. You can assume your `s:GetPairs()` results in `[ ['"', '"'], ["'", "'"] ]` -- `s:GetPairs()` returns the list of brackets pairs registered for the current buffer.

```
function! s:outer_blocks() abort
  let crt_pairs = copy(s:GetPairs(0))
  call extend(crt_pairs, s:GetPairs(1))
  let matches = {}
  for p in crt_pairs
    if p[0] != p[1] " searchpos doesn't work in that case
      let pos = searchpairpos(p[0], '', p[1], 'cWn', "lh#syntax#is_a_comment('.')")
      call s:Verbose('Testing searchpos(%1) -> %2', p, pos)
    elseif p[0] =~ '["'']'
      " Stuff which can be checked with vi', vi"
      let crt_pos = getpos('.')
      let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
            \.restore('@a')
            \.register('call setpos(".", '.string(crt_pos).')')
      try
        let @a = ''
        silent! exe 'normal! "aya'.p[0]
        " 2 chars are to be expected for open and close
        if lh#encoding#strlen(@a) >= lh#encoding#strlen(p[0].p[1])
          " In two steps because it may fail
          " -- it shouldn't though thanks to len(@a) >= 2 * len(open)
          exe 'normal! v'
          silent! exe 'normal! a'.p[0]
          silent! exe "normal! \<esc>"
          let pos = getpos('.')[1:2]
        else
          let pos = [0,0]
        endif
        if 0
          " getpos doesn't seem to work...
          let pos = getpos('`>')[1:2]
          if getpos('`<')[1:2] == pos
            let pos = [0,0]
          endif
        endif
        call s:Verbose('Testing va%1 -> %2 - %3', p[0], pos, @a)
      finally
        call cleanup.finalize()
      endtry
    else
      let pos = searchpos(p[0], 'cWnb', 'lh#syntax#is_a_comment(".")')
      if  pos != [0,0]
        let pos = searchpos(p[1], 'cWn', 'lh#syntax#is_a_comment(".")')
      endif
      call s:Verbose('Testing /%1 -> %2', p[0], pos)
    endif
    if pos != [0,0]
      let matches[p[0]] = pos
    endif
  endfor
  call s:Verbose('Containing bracket pairs: %1', matches)
  return matches
endfunction
```

Comment: Possibly you're thinking of `rhysd/vim-textobj-anyblock`?  (Although there are probably a number of similar plugins)  Edit: `gcmt/wildfire.vim` also looks close to what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). It's easy to add `"` or `'`.
For example, `ysw"` will add `"` to surround the current word.

Comment: If you read the code of in OP's question they already use vim-surround. What they want to do is a bit more complexe than simply adding the surrounding quotes.